# Open new instance of InAppBrowser in Ionic

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

This is regarding `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

How to create new instance of In-AppBrowser each time it creates? As per the documentation, `create` method will opens a URL in a new InAppBrowser instance, the current browser instance, or the system browser.

I want to opens a URL in a new InAppBrowser instance every-time.

I have tried different initialisations as below, But in both cases it seems using existing instance after first time load. In addition to that I have clear cache in the options.

```
import {InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser)

// use global instance
showGlobleBrowser(){
let browser = this.iab.create(payURL, '_blank', {inapp browser options here...});
}

// use new instance
showNewBrowser(){
let browser = new InAppBrowser().create(contactUsUrl, '_blank',{inapp browser options here...});
}
```

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I am loading a custom chat page inside in-app browser. Due to some technical difficulty on the chat web page, I want to initiate a new chat every time user opens the page through in-app browser.

Comment: I see. That could consume a lot of memory, do you really have to allow multiple chats to be open at once?

Comment: Why dont you integrate chat in your application.

Comment: Due to urgency of the requirement, we decided to implement chat feature only on the web first. Then consume same page on mobile app via in-app browser.

Comment: @AluanHaddad not really. I don't want to opens multiple chats at once. I only needs to opens a fresh instance of the page every-time when user opens in-app browser. This behaviour happens correctly when I kill the app and reopen. But when Im on the same page(a native mobile page) and open inapp browser and the close it, then re-open, it will use previous instance.